# Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results... stuck when importing SASS modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass, create-react-app

## Problem

When there are SASS variables imported in any TypeScript file, saving changes gets you stuck on `Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...` + browser tab with open devserver hangs.

What am I missing? Am I running out of resources? Is there a better way to import SASS variables into TypeScript files?

## Files

_variables.scss

[image]

_export.module.scss

[image]

variables import
[image]

Relevant webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    exclude: /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { importLoaders: 3, sourceMap: true }
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [Function: plugins],
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          root: './src'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: { sourceMap: true }
      }
    ],
    sideEffects: true
  },
  {
    test: /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 3,
          sourceMap: true,
          modules: { getLocalIdent: [Function: getLocalIdent] }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [Function: plugins],
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          root: './src'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: { sourceMap: true }
      }
    ]
  },
```

## Edit

In webpack I was mistakenly popping the **ignorePlugin**. Removing this mistake solved the browser hanging issue, but not `Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...` issue

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute paths makes it harder to share the config with other developers. You can use the name of the loader directly in the config:

```
{
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    exclude: /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { importLoaders: 3, sourceMap: true }
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [Function: plugins],
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          root: './src'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: { sourceMap: true }
      }
    ],
    sideEffects: true
  },
  {
    test: /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 3,
          sourceMap: true,
          modules: { getLocalIdent: [Function: getLocalIdent] }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [Function: plugins],
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          root: './src'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: { sourceMap: true }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Could it be that what I have is what CRA outputs? We are using rescripts to tweak CRA a bit, but we have never touched said paths. Will use your edit for more legibility. Thank you